# mysql - query database for expenses and debts

Tags: mysql

With respect to the sample table below, and keeping in mind the following definitions,

- start, end and timestamp are all unix timestamps
- Definition: duration = ((end - start)/3600), that is, in hours

I would like to get the following mysql query:

1. Group by student and calculate all money spent by each student - that is, (duration x cost)

This is what I got and it works, but is incomplete!

```
SELECT student, SUM(ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600)) AS expenses 
FROM schedules GROUP BY student;
```

AND (this one does not work, but the idea is actually what I want to attain)

```
SELECT student, SUM(SELECT ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600) FROM schedules WHERE paid = 1) AS expenses,  SUM(SELECT ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600) FROM schedules WHERE paid = 0) AS debts FROM schedules GROUP BY student;
```

My BIGGEST problem is with calculating expenses from today into the past as well as debts if the date of today is greater than start and paid is still set to 0

Thank you all for your ideas!

Sample Table

```
id  meta_id start       end     admin   student tutor   course  cost    paid    paydate      timestamp
18  4   1359867600  1359867690  jnc banjune cameron 2   90  1   1361521193  1359881165
19  4   1360472400  1360472490  jnc banjune cameron 2   90  1   1361521195  1359881165
20  4   1359867600  1359867690  jnc saadcore    cameron 2   90  1   1361547064  1359881165
25  6   1359914400  1359919800  jnc johndoe cameron 3   35  1   1361547080  1359893058
26  6   1360000800  1360006200  jnc johndoe cameron 3   35  0   0       1359893058
27  6   1360087200  1360092600  jnc johndoe cameron 3   35  0   0       1359893058
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  First, don't ask multiple questions in one post.  Second, show your work.  If you just dump a bunch of questions it looks like you're too lazy to even attempt the problem and nobody is going to help you.  You have to make an effort.  I recommend you delete this question and try again. Ask only the first question and show what you have attempted.  If the answer doesn't help you with all the questions, post the next one showing your work... etc.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually done my assignment. I have shown what I've done in the question(s) and I've pointed out what I want: With Nr. 1 for example, my BIGGEST problem is with calculating expenses from today into the past as well as debts if the date of today is greater than start and paid is still set to 0

Comment: SELECT student, SUM(SELECT ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600) FROM schedules WHERE paid = 1) AS expenses,  SUM(SELECT ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600) FROM schedules WHERE paid = 0) AS debts FROM schedules GROUP BY student;

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this query does not work!


SELECT student, IF(paid= 1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start) <= now(), SUM(ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600)), 0) as expenses, IF(paid= 0 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start) <= now(), SUM(ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600)), 0) as debts FROM schedules GROUP BY student;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired solution

```
SELECT 
student, 
SUM(CASE WHEN paid = 1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start) <= now() THEN ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600) 
         ELSE 0 END) as expenses, 
SUM(CASE WHEN paid = 0 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start) <= now() THEN ceil(cost*(end-start)/3600) 
         ELSE 0 END) as debts 
FROM schedules 
GROUP BY student;
```